# Draw an arc inside the angle drawing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, geometry

I am having three points which come from the user clicking on a canvas.

I draw the lines to join these points so that it forms an angle.

Now I want to draw an arc which denotes that it is an angle (The same as the one shown in the picture of the question [How to draw the arc of a three point angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441793/how-to-draw-the-arc-of-a-three-point-angle)).

The solution on the above link discusses only for the static angle. I have the three points on which the angle is to be drawn. I tried that example but it does not show the correct angle.

Will anyone please guide me how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667072/wpf-how-to-draw-arc-with-radius-and-start-and-stop-angle

Comment: @Freelancer, DataBinding, Layouts, Panels, Custom Controls, Dependency Properties vagere mahatvache aahet. Mala tumhi mail karu shakta majha website varun. Majhi website majha profile war namud aahe.

Comment: @Freelancer, I checked that question too. It does not help.

Comment: nikam bhau, mala tumhi mention kelya paiki dependancy property sodun sagala yeta. 1 yr experience sathi itakach vichartat?

Comment: bhari resume aahe tumacha.

Comment: Thank you, @Freelancer, mala nuktach 1 year jhala aahe... Majha hishobane evhdha mahit ashna pushkal aahe. FB war ahat tar add kara mala. Apan tithe bolu. Ithe bolna barobar nahi.

Comment: ho-ho, nakki add karen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31435/discussion-between-pankaj-nikam-and-freelancer)